# JavaScript array traces out as having a value before a value is pushed to it

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a project that tracks clicked links on a website. I am trying to store the clicked links in the local storage object. To be able to work with the links in my code, I am creating a local array that gets the urls (clicked links) from the local storage.

During some debugging I noticed that the local array has a value right after instantiation before a value is pushed to it.

Code:

```
console.log("before instantiation");

var clickedLinksArrTest = [];

console.log("after instantiation");

console.log("before pushing the url");

console.log("clickedLinksArrTest ", clickedLinksArrTest);

clickedLinksArrTest.push(localStorage["clickedLinks"]);

console.log("after pushing the url");

console.log("clickedLinksArrTest ", clickedLinksArrTest);
```

What I am seeing in the browser console is this:

[image: Screen shot of browser console output]

It looks like there's already a value at index 0 in the array even before I am pushing the url into it. I am trying to track down one particular error and I don't know if this might be causing it so I would like to understand what's going on here in case it actually is the cause for the bug I'm trying to fix.

Comment: Hover over the little `i` icon.

Comment: The console isn't always good at maintaining the state of objects when they are logged. If you exit your code after your first log, it will be empty.

Comment: @SLaks It says "Value below was evaluated just now". What does that mean? Is the browser "pre-calculating" what values an array will hold before it processes console logs?

Answer (score 1):

To see the difference try this :

```
console.log("before instantiation");
```

var clickedLinksArrTest = [];

console.log("after instantiation");

console.log("before pushing the url");

console.log("clickedLinksArrTest ", clickedLinksArrTest.slice(0));

clickedLinksArrTest.push(localStorage["clickedLinks"]);

console.log("after pushing the url");

console.log("clickedLinksArrTest ", clickedLinksArrTest);

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the concept of mutability/immutability. I am reading up on it now and I don't yet entirely understand it. I tried your code and it does clear the array. But what does that mean in practice? Does this mean I have to perform a slice operation every time I instantiate an array just to make sure it doesn't have a value in it before being assigned one? And how exactly does the concept of mutability/immutability explain what I'm seeing in the browser console? Is the browser "pre-calculating" what values an array will hold before it processes console logs?

Comment: Did you delete the remark about mutability/immutability? If so, why? Does it not pertain to this issue after all?

Comment: yes I've deleted it because,  it's not exactly mutation in this case. The mutation is when you do this
`array1 = []; array2 = array1;`
...  in this case whenever you change the array1 this change will be done also in array2 (mutation).. because they point to the same reference in the memory.

You see the same in your console, when you try to see the state of the array "before pushing". The console.log just show you the current state of the array. To see the difference you first have to make e copy of that array with its current state.

Comment: Ok, I understand what mutability refers to now but I'm still not clear on what's going on in the browser log. You say `console.log` shows me the current state of the array but since I'm tracing it before pushing a value, shouldn't the state be `length = 0` and no value at index 0?

Comment: No, the current state is the last state of the array ;]. You can see that the log of the array before pushing seems to be empty because it shows `clickedLinksArrTest > []` but when you click on ">" to see what the content of array, you see that it is not empty ;] ... that's because of the reference

Comment: Right, I did notice that the brackets are empty `clickedLinksArrTest > []` like it's an empty array and only the detail view shows it as populated. Does this mean that I can essentially disregard the detail view and trust that the array is actually empty? Or does it mean that array is actually populated and this could cause an issue?

Comment: Yes, that is what it means, that the array is empty. At the moment you try to reference/access it, it will show you the current state. You can do another test, like:
`g=[];console.log(g);g.push(1);console.log(g);g.pop();console.log(g);`
now try to see the second console.log which says that the array is [1]